# Flutter update parent UI from child

Tags: flutter

I have a child widget which has has a button that has a callback function in it. The widget is called `showMessage(callback)`. after a future, i return the showMessage() function which returns a widget. Now the button in this widget should simply show the main widget if clicked, i.e. give the user an option to retry or post a new record to the api.

Here is my code

Parent:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: PrimaryAppColor,
      title: const Text('MTN Airtime Top Up'),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder<SaleResponseModel>(
        future: futResponse,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SaleResponseModel> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return screenMessageDisplay(context, "Top-up complete", Icons.check_circle, Colors.green, true, true, () {
                shouldShowScreen = false;
              }); //_showScreen();
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return screenLoader("Topping up, please wait ...");
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return _showScreen();
              } else {
                var message = "";
                if (snapshot.data.message != null) message = snapshot.data.message;

                if (snapshot.data.statusCode == 200) {
                  var sale = snapshot.data.sale;
                  return _showMessage(null, null, null);
                } else {
                  return _showScreen();
                }
              }
          }
        }),
  );
}
```

CHILD:

```
Widget screenMessageDisplay(BuildContext context, message, icon, iconColor, okBtn, retryBtn, retryCallback) {
  Widget _showOkBtn() {
    if (okBtn)
      return AppButton("OK", () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }, 100);
    else {
      return Text("");
    }
  }

  Widget _showRetryBtn() {
    if (retryBtn && retryCallback != null)
      return AppButton("RETRY", () {
        retryCallback();
      }, 100);
    else {
      return Text("");
    }
  }

  return new Center(
      child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      new Icon(icon, color: iconColor, size: 60.0),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      new Text(
        message,
        style: LoadingTextStyle,
      ),
      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        _showOkBtn(),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        _showRetryBtn(),
      ])
    ],
  ));
```

Is this the right way to go about it ? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your example code is incomplete. For example, where is `_showMessage`? Can you provide a full example?

Comment: screenMessageDisplay takes 7 positional parameters!! That's difficult to read. Better to use named parameters.